# How to center an image within a col element

Tags: html, css

having issues making an image centre
css on same .php file as the code

```css
<style type="text/css">
 
div.item {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.item img {
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="full-sec" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="giveaway" class="body-sec">
                <h2 class="main-title">UPCOMING GIVEAWAY</h2>
    <centre>
    <h4 class="sub-title"><?php echo $giveaway_title; ?></h4>
    </centre>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="main-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="full-sec" class="col-xs-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="item">
       <img src="http://community.edgecast.steamstatic.com/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV08u_mpSOhcjnI7TDglRc7cF4n-T--Y3nj1H6-hBrMW_3LIOWdlU_MlGDqwO6wrvq15C6vp-bnHY36SAm4XbYl0SwhgYMMLJqUag1Og/360fx360f" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

live version can be found here: http://178.62.99.182/giveaway.php

can anyone help please?

Comment: Remove these properties from this div.item {
    /* height: 300px; */
    /* width: 300px; */
    /* display: table-cell; */
    /* margin-left: auto; */
    /* margin-right: auto; */
    /* text-align: center; */

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the parent element of the image the margin auto. Not the image itself.

```
div.item {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.item img {
    width: 100%;
}
```